# Как ограничить количество символом в QlinedeEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня есть приложение `Pyqt5`.

Я хочу сделать так чтоб в `QLineEdit` можно было **вводить только цифры**.

**Максимум 2 цифры**. От 1 до 100. Надо это сделать для Linedit2

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from nvutidesign import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

**nvutidesign.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(870, 569)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 220, 201, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 781, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(72)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(97, 118, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"pIntValidator.setRange(1, 95)")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(99999)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 841, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 480, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(231, 231, 231);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 71, 16))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 350, 28, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(507, 350, 161, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Меньше"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Больше"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возможный выигрыш"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0.00"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Процент"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "700"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Баланс"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пополнить"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti 2020©"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0-0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "999999 - 999999"))
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пример, в котором вы хотите так сделать.

Comment: Давайте не играться в догадки, опубликуйте модуль `nvutidesign.py`

Comment: Вы в трех предложениях указываете разные имена переменных: `Linedit2`, `linedit`, `linedit2`.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9a3o9zyxlr2avfe/nvutidesign.py/file Вот ссылка на

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Класс **QIntValidator** предоставляет валидатор, который гарантирует,
>    что строка содержит допустимое целое число в указанном диапазоне.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit_taxRate= QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_taxRate.setValidator(
            QtGui.QIntValidator(
                1,                 # int minimum
                99                 # int maximum
            )
        )
        self.setCentralWidget(self.lineEdit_taxRate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from nvutidesign import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(870, 569)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 220, 201, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 781, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(72)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(97, 118, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"pIntValidator.setRange(1, 95)")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(99999)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(3)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 841, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 480, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(231, 231, 231);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 71, 16))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 350, 28, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(507, 350, 161, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Меньше"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Больше"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возможный выигрыш"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0.00"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Процент"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "700"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Баланс"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пополнить"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti 2020©"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0-0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "999999 - 999999"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.lineEdit_2.setValidator(
            QtGui.QIntValidator(
                1,                 # int minimum
                99                 # int maximum
            )
        )

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает у меня есть код в котором есть linedit я там хочу сделать.

Comment: @ДимаНейзвестный что у вас не работает, пример который я опубликовал ?

Comment: Пример работает но мне надо это вставить в свои дизайн код linedit2.

Comment: @ДимаНейзвестный для `lineEdit_2` :) Пробуйте.

Comment: Можно максимум 99 мне надо 95

Comment: @ДимаНейзвестный Я добавил ответ как вам правильно надо сделать. 
Но это пусть будет последнее ваше уточнение в данном вопросе,
т.к. вы начинали с вопроса `Как ограничить количество символом в QlinedeEdit`, 
а сейчас мы уже обсуждаем число `95`.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Update 2**

> Можно максимум не 99, а  **95**

Все можно, но `Виджет QLineEdit представляет собой однострочный текстовый редактор.`, а вам нужен `QSpinBox предназначен для обработки целых чисел...`, поэтому вам проще поменять виджет в модуле `nvutidesign.py`. **Обратите внимание на изменения, которые я внес в модуле `nvutidesign.py`**

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from nvutidesign import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.lineEdit_2.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setRange(0, 95) 
        self.lineEdit_2.setPrefix(" Процент :  ")
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**nvutidesign.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(870, 569)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(870, 569))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 380, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(141, 142, 161);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 220, 201, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 781, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(72)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(97, 118, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"pIntValidator.setRange(1, 95)")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(99999)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
#        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
#
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)

        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 260, 221, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"border: 2px solid gray;           \n"
"border-radius: 10px;")

#        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(3)
#        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
#        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 460, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 490, 41, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 500, 841, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 480, 61, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(231, 231, 231);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(162, 162, 162);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);\n"
"border-radius: 5px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(138, 138, 138);\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 550, 71, 16))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 350, 28, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(507, 350, 161, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Меньше"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Больше"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возможный выигрыш"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0.00"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сумма"))
####        
#        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Процент"))
####
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Половина"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удвоить"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мин."))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Макс."))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "700"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Баланс"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пополнить"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вывести"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nvuti 2020©"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0-0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "999999 - 999999"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]